# Where should HTML Preloader be placed?

Tags: javascript, html, preloader

I am making a custom preloader for my site. It works fine on localhost but on the live site, the div shows no animation and the text is just placed at the bottom of the site.

```
<!-- Preloader -->
  <div id="ctn-preloader" class="ctn-preloader">
    <div class="animation-preloader">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
      <div class="txt-loading">
        <span data-text-preloader="P" class="letters-loading">
          P
        </span>
        <span data-text-preloader="U" class="letters-loading">
          U
        </span>
        <span data-text-preloader="M" class="letters-loading">
          M
        </span>
        <span data-text-preloader="S" class="letters-loading">
          S
        </span>
        <span data-text-preloader="A" class="letters-loading">
          A
      </div>
      <p class="text-center">Loading</p>
    </div>
    <div class="loader">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 loader-section">
          <div class="bg"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the JS code that hides the preloader

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('no-scroll-y');
    $('#ctn-preloader').fadeOut('slow');
  });
```

The HTML was initially just before the closing body tag before adding script files. It worked fine on localhost but not online. 
I shifted it to be just below the opening body tag. Now it loads endlessly on localhost except the index page but still doesn't load online.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It's fixed now. I couldn't figure out the actual problem though so this is kind of a hack. I added the preloader html, the style and the javascript code all to the same header file. This way I guess, no file has to be required for the preloader to work correctly

Answer (score 0):

have you checked if jQuery is required correctly ? you will need to have jQuery before your  since the loading is in order.

Other than that i see no errors ! 
it would be very helpful if you can show us the whole page code and if there is any errors shows up in the console.

Comment: Thanks, I checked this and it is required correctly. Most of my included scripts though have the defer attribute added to them to improve page load time. That must have been the problem

Answer (score 0):

JQuery `.load` has been deprecated since 1.8

Use `.on("load", function() { })` and it should work fine as it does below:

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
    $('body').removeClass('no-scroll-y');
    $('#ctn-preloader').fadeOut('slow');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="ctn-preloader" class="ctn-preloader">
    <div class="animation-preloader">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
      <div class="txt-loading">
        <span data-text-preloader="P" class="letters-loading">
          P
        </span>
        <span data-text-preloader="U" class="letters-loading">
          U
        </span>
        <span data-text-preloader="M" class="letters-loading">
          M
        </span>
        <span data-text-preloader="S" class="letters-loading">
          S
        </span>
        <span data-text-preloader="A" class="letters-loading">
          A
      </div>
      <p class="text-center">Loading</p>
    </div>
    <div class="loader">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 loader-section">
          <div class="bg"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // code here
});
```

or

```
$(function(){
    // code here
});
```